# left and right frame with buttons in them

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I want to create two frames next to each other with widgets in a mainframe, but I don't know how to make them both clickable, and I'm sure my code can be cleaned up. Any help is appreciated!

I started off with just making a single frame with widgets and than go from there, but my main problem is that the list constructor can only take one argument. I want to be able to use the self.squares variable for both frames but I'm not sure how to do that so I set up another square dictionary for the second frame but I think that makes things unnecessarily long. Here is my code below. The #here is where I'm having the most trouble.

```
class Board(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, length, width):  # self=Frame, parent=root

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.config(height=100 * self.length, width=100 * self.width)
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame()
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame()
        self.pack()

        self.squares = {}
        self.squares2 = {}
        self.ranks = string.ascii_lowercase
        self.buttons_pressed = 0
        self.turns = 0
        self.sq1 = None  # first square clicked
        self.sq2 = None
        self.sq1_button = None  # button associated with the square clicked
        self.sq2_button = None
        self.set_squares()

    def select_piece(self, button):
        if self.buttons_pressed == 0:
            self.sq1 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)] #here
            self.sq1_button = button
            self.buttons_pressed += 1

        elif self.buttons_pressed == 1:  # stores square and button of second square selected
            self.sq2 = list(self.squares.keys())[list(self.squares.values()).index(button)]
            self.sq2_button = button
            if self.sq2 == self.sq1:  # prevents self-destruction and allows the user to choose a new piece
                self.buttons_pressed = 0
                return
            if True:
                self.squares[self.sq2].config(image=self.sq1_button["image"])
                self.squares[self.sq2].image = self.sq1_button["image"]
                self.squares[self.sq1].config(image=self.white_images["blank.png"])  # clears sq1
                self.squares[self.sq1].image = self.white_images["blank.png"]
                self.buttons_pressed = 0
                return

    def set_squares(self):  # fills frame with buttons representing squares

        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                b = tk.Button(self.frame1, bg=self.square_color, activebackground="lawn green")
                b.grid(row=8 - x, column=y)
                b2 = tk.Button(self.frame2, bg=self.square_color, activebackground="lawn green")
                b2.grid(row=8 - x, column=y)
                pos = self.ranks[x] + str(y + 1)
                self.squares.setdefault(pos, b,)  # creates list of square positions
                self.squares2.setdefault(pos, b2)
                self.squares[pos].config(command=lambda key=self.squares[pos]: self.select_piece(key))
                self.squares2[pos].config(command=lambda key=self.squares2[pos]: self.select_piece(key))

    def set_pieces(self):  # places pieces in starting positions
        dict_rank1_pieces = {"a1": "dirt.png", "b1": "fire.png", "c1": "metal.png", "d1": "water.png", "e1": "wood.png"}

        for key in dict_rank1_pieces:  # inserts images into buttons
            starting_piece = dict_rank1_pieces[key]
            self.squares[key].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
            self.squares[key].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]
            self.squares2[key].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
            self.squares2[key].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]
            self.frame1.pack(side='left')
            self.frame2.pack(side='right')

        for rank in range(2, 6):  # fill rest with blank pieces
            for file in range(5):
                starting_piece = "blank.png"
                pos = self.ranks[file] + str(rank)
                self.squares[pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
                self.squares[pos].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]
                self.squares2[pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
                self.squares2[pos].image = self.white_images[starting_piece]


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
board = Board(root, 5, 5)
board.import_pieces()
board.set_pieces()
board.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same `self.squares` for both the frames, you need to make the *keys* (currently they are something like "a1", "b1", etc) unique.  One of the suggestion is to use a tuple of `(idx, key)` instead as the new *key*:

- `idx` is 0 for the first frame, 1 for the second frame
- `key` is the current *key* used, i.e. "a1", "b1", etc

Below is the required modifications:

```py
class Board(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def set_squares(self):  # fills frame with buttons representing squares

        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                pos = self.ranks[x] + str(y + 1)
                for i, frame in enumerate((self.frame1, self.frame2)):
                    b = tk.Button(frame, bg=self.square_color, activebackground="lawn green")
                    b.grid(row=8 - x, column=y, sticky="nsew")
                    b.config(command=lambda key=b: self.select_piece(key))
                    # use tuple as key
                    self.squares[i,pos] = b

    def set_pieces(self):  # places pieces in starting positions
        dict_rank1_pieces = {"a1": "dirt.png", "b1": "fire.png", "c1": "metal.png", "d1": "water.png", "e1": "wood.png"}

        for key in dict_rank1_pieces:  # inserts images into buttons
            starting_piece = dict_rank1_pieces[key]
            # use tuple as key
            self.squares[0,key].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
            self.squares[1,key].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
            # suggest to move below two lines to __init__()
            self.frame1.pack(side='left')
            self.frame2.pack(side='right')

        for rank in range(2, 6):  # fill rest with blank pieces
            for file in range(5):
                starting_piece = "blank.png"
                pos = self.ranks[file] + str(rank)
                # use tuple as key
                self.squares[0,pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])
                self.squares[1,pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece])

...
```

*Note that currently you have created the two frames with buttons as children of root window, not `Board`.  Is it what you want actually?*

---

Updated `set_pieces()` to put images at the very left column of left frame and the very right column of right frame:

```py
def set_pieces(self):  # places pieces in starting positions
    dict_rank_pieces = {"a": "dirt.png", "b": "fire.png", "c": "metal.png", "d": "water.png", "e": "wood.png"}

    blank_piece = "blank.png"
    for rank in range(1, 6):  # fill rest with blank pieces
        for file in range(5):
            starting_piece = dict_rank_pieces[self.ranks[file]]
            pos = self.ranks[file] + str(rank)
            self.squares[0,pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece if rank == 1 else blank_piece])
            self.squares[1,pos].config(image=self.white_images[starting_piece if rank == 5 else blank_piece])

    self.frame1.pack(side='left')
    self.frame2.pack(side='right')
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will apply this to my code soon. What is the difference between the two frames being a child of root window and not Board?

Comment: If the two frames are not children of `Board`, why are they created inside `Board.__init__()`?

Comment: I suppose that was an oversight of mine. Can you inform me how to make them children of Board?

Comment: Use `self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)`. Same for `self.frame2`.

Comment: I would also like to has images in the very left column on the left frame and the very right column on the right frame but the for loops for rank and file don't allow me to do that, would you know how I could?

Comment: @WillemBrockSmith Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but I have one last question and I will be done. How do I make is so that the images can only move in their respective frames?

Comment: @WillemBrockSmith The first item of the *key* is the frame index that you can use to check whether the selected buttons are in the same frame.

Comment: I'm having trouble. For example if  ```self.squares[0, self.sq2_button] in self.squares[1, pos]:
self.buttons_pressed = 0``` give me KeyError: (0, None) and if I try self.white_images it gives me "unhashable type: 'dict'"

Comment: It is better to raise another question as it is not related to this question.

Comment: @WillemBrockSmith If it solves your problem, consider upvote and accept it as the answer.

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation. I have however accepted your response as the answer.